# SQL cumulative sum with mutilple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, cumulative-sum

I have a input table as this:

```
date    ID    Flag 
01.01    A     0
01.02    A     0
01.03    A     1
01.04    A     1 
01.05    A     1
01.06    A     0
01.07    A     1
01.08    A     1
01.09    A     0
01.01    B     1
01.02    B     0
01.03    B     1
01.04    B     1 
01.05    B     1
01.06    B     1
01.07    B     1
01.08    B     0
01.09    B     0
```

I would like to calculate the cumulative sum of the flag for each, but the calculation should be refreshed if the flag is equal to 0 once again.

So, the output table should be:

```
date    ID    Flag   CUMSUM
01.01    A     0        0
01.02    A     0        0
01.03    A     1        1
01.04    A     1        2
01.05    A     1        3
01.06    A     0        0
01.07    A     1        1
01.08    A     1        2
01.09    A     0        0
01.01    B     1        1
01.02    B     0        0
01.03    B     1        1
01.04    B     1        2
01.05    B     1        3
01.06    B     1        4
01.07    B     1        5
01.08    B     0        0
01.09    B     0        0
```

So, any suggestion to solve this issue?
I tried with this:

```
sum(FLAG) over (partition by ID order by date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

But i have no idea how can I "refresh" the cumulative calculation, any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign a grouping.  The grouping is the number of `0`s before each row.  Then use that for partitioning:

```
select t.*,
       (case when flag = 1
             then sum(flag) over (partition by id, grp order by date)
             else 0
        end) as cumulative_sum
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when flag = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by date) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

Note:  The window frame specification (`rows between . . .`) is not needed assuming that the dates are unique (as in your sample data).  So, I just left it out.

Also, you can simplify the calculation in the subquery to:

```
sum(1 - flag = 0) over (partition by id order by date) as grp
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is an excellent idea to assign a new group.    Thanks again.